# Script selection of options inside running program

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I want to run a program that expects two inputs after executing to decide how it will run. Like so:

```
$ program <input_file>
Running program
1. Option one
2. Option two
select an option: <Expects `1` or `2`>

3. Option three
4. Option four
select an option: <Expects `3` or `4`>

Running with selected options.
```

I would like to run it for many input files for which the same options will be selected. Right now I do:

```
$ for i in *; do program $i; done
```

With this I have to select the options manually for every file. How can I pass the options to the program to automate it? Something like:

```
$ for i in *; do program $i < <options>; done
```

The program repeats the available options if the correct one is not selected. So when I tried with `{echo 2; echo 4}` and `echo "2\n4\n"` it gets stuck on the first option selection.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to Elseif everything

```
IF "%ID%"=="0" ( ... & ... & ... ) ELSE ^
IF "%ID%"=="1" ( ... ) ELSE ^
IF "%ID%"=="2" ( ... ) ELSE ^
REM default case...
```

Second option

```
echo Choose from the list given below:
echo [1] Option 1
echo [2] Option 2
echo [3] Option 3

set /a one=1
set /a two=2
set /a three=3
set /a four=4
set input=
set /p input= Enter your choice:
if %input% equ %one% goto Z if NOT goto Start2
if %input% equ %two% goto X if NOT goto Start2
if %input% equ %three% goto C if NOT goto Start2
if %input% geq %four% goto N

:Z
cls
echo You have selected : Option 1
set option=Option 1
echo %year%
call:branches option

pause
exit
```

---

### Source

[StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423443/switch-statement-equivalent-in-windows-batch-file) they have more knowledge in batch and programming language

Comment: Does anyone knows about a SWITCH CASE or SELECT CASE in batch ?

Comment: I'm really confused by your answer. Maybe because I wasn't clear with my redaction. I want to use a bash script to interact with the program without me having to select the options (I don't want to type them every time I run it).

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood you, so to clarify, you want a script who runs ask the user to choose between some options and run the code from the selected option? If I'm still wrong can you maybe do a programming flowchart?

Answer (score 0):

> when I tried with `{echo 2; echo 4}` and `echo "2\n4\n"` it gets stuck on the first option selection.

It's not clear to me how you tried this, but:

- `{echo 2; echo 4}` is syntactically invalid; you want `{ echo 2; echo 4; }`;
- `echo "2\n4\n"` just prints `2\n4\n`; you want `echo -ne "2\n4\n"` (note: various implementations of `echo` may behave differently, but since `echo` is a builtin in `bash` and you tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I assume you use the builtin).

I would say this *might* work:

```
for i in *; do { echo 2; echo 4; } | program "$i"; done
```

---

I can imagine `program` silently depletes and discards its stdin before it asks for options, or uses another trick that makes the above solution fail. In this case try `expect`, if available.

[`man 1 expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) states:

> `expect` is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs according to a script. Following the script, `expect` knows what can be expected from a program and what the correct response should be.
>
> […]
>
> In general, `expect` is useful for running any program which requires interaction between the program and the user. All that is necessary is that the interaction can be characterized programmatically.

This example sends 2 and 4 when the program asks for them:

```
expect -c '
        spawn program ./input_file
        expect "2. Option two"
        expect "select an option:*"
        send "2\r"
        expect "4. Option four"
        expect "select an option:*"
        send "4\r"
        expect eof'
```

Using this with shell variables requires proper quoting and escaping:

```
for i in *; do
  expect -c "
        spawn program \"$i\"
        expect \"2. Option two\"
        expect \"select an option:*\"
        send \"2\r\"
        expect \"4. Option four\"
        expect \"select an option:*\"
        send \"4\r\"
        expect eof"
done
```