# Using built-in commands from running process in script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, process

So lately I've been trying to quit a running process in a clean manner, through its 'quit' command. 
If I don't go through the entire quitting process it creates a .lck file and I don't want that.

I've been unable to succeed, I've tried multiple approaches such as **echoing 'quit'** and **\015, \012, \n** to **/proc/pid/fd/0**, but none of these managed to validate what was in the buffer.
I've tried to screen a terminal, and reptyr the process into it so it goes into a terminal but doing so I can't find a way to emulate the enter key.

So, since it seems that no matter what I try I can't find how to validate a text buffer, I decided that I should use that built-in quit directly and not trying to input it.

Is there ways to use another process commands directly ? When I try

```
quit | reptyr <process pid>
```

for instance, it says that quit isn't a recognized command, because the shell is trying to execute it in its own environment and I wish to execute it in the other process environment.

NOTE: Some info about said running process, I have to provide several input to quit it.

- press Ctlr + C to stop it
  It then swap to SimDebug mode which just provides infos should I press enter a few times. It is in read mode looking like

  SimDebug>
- There I should write quit and press enter, then q and enter, n and enter then lastly enter.

I manage in my script to do the 1st point by using kill -INT  and I'm stuck with the rest.

EDIT : I can skip some of those task using the SIGTERM as suggested, although it gets me to the last read

> Do you want to do a checkpoint (Y/N)
>   _

And there I can't do another SIGTERM, a SIGKILL pops up an error message and a .lck file is created. I only do need to feed a "n" or "y" inside it.
I will take a look at the expect since now I have the question but i'm still wondering how to use it to be listening to the process and not the terminal in which i'm running the script.

Comment: `echo quit | reptyr` will send `quit` as standard input to `reptyr`. Making it quit immediately sounds like a weird thing to do, though.

Comment: For general approach research [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect). See [this example](https://superuser.com/a/1293621/432690).

Comment: I'm not trying to quit reptyr but the process inside.

Comment: I'm not sure expect would be appropriate here since I don't have any expectation, it's just a console in read mode without any prior questions.

Comment: `I've been trying to quit a running process in a clean manner` – Well writen programs quit gracefully on `SIGTERM` (as opposed to `SIGKILL`).

Answer (score 0):

Run the program in `tmux` (or run `reptyr` in `tmux` to "hijack" already running process, if you need; e.g. `tmux new-session reptyr "$pid_to_hijack"`). Then you can do this from another terminal:

```
pane='$0:@0.1'
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" C-c                # a way to send Ctrl+C
sleep 2                                      # let the program react (you may or may not need it)
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" Enter Enter Enter  # "should I press enter a few times"
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" quit Enter         # "I should write quit and press enter"
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" q Enter            # "then q and enter"
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" n Enter            # "n and enter"
tmux send-keys -t "$pane" Enter              # "then lastly enter"
```

where the example `$0:@0.1` identifies the pane in which your program runs (you must single-quote this string, otherwise the shell will expand `$0`). If you name your tmux session(s) and window(s), then this string may be like `mysession:mywindow.0`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you're trying to send command to a "subshell". Let's say something like running command `quit()` in a python shell? Or any other programs that waits for an input?

If it's that what you want, I think you're looking for something like :

```
$> python <<< "quit() python <<< "<many instructions here>" python <
$> file_containing_instructions.py #with quit() at the end python << END
$> <instructions> <on_many_lines> END
```

Now if you're trying to keep a reference to a running process and then sent instructions to it later, then the only thing I can tell you at the very moment is `coproc`. You can learn a bit about it with `help coproc`, there is more in `man bash` and even more in `info bash`.

Good luck

EDIT: Just came back on that tab and saw the crapy formating so I fixed it. Also, I wanted to add that I haven't been able to make it work with Python but most likely it's doable, althogh with other shell like bash it works like that.

```
$> coproc PRC { bash; } &
$> echo 'echo $PATH' >&${PRC[1]}
$> read -t1 -u ${PRC[0]} resp
$> echo $resp
/the/PATH/is/printed
$> echo 'exit' >&${PRC[1]}
$> jobs
[1]+ Done
```